# How to make dinamic query for view use stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

Would you like to help me to create a stored procedure with case like this.

I have query like this :

```
select * from db_2014.tablename
union
select * from db_2015.tablename
union
select * from db_2016.tablename
```

But the database name (year's name) should get from one table, that has been stored the field of 'year'.
Table that has 'year' for database name:

```
select Year from db_Years.tablename;
```

And i'm stuck with my stored procedure :

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
     ROLLBACK;
    END;

    SET @isunion = " union ";
    SET @queryGetYears = "select Year from db_name.tablename group by Year order by Year asc";

    /*LOOPING RESULT OF @queryGetYears*/
    SET @queryFetchDBByYear = CONCAT("select * from db_","-getFieldYear-",".tablename",@isunion);
    /*END LOOPING*/

    /*END SHOWING THE RESULT OF @queryFetchDBByYear*/

  PREPARE stmt from @queryGetYears;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Is it posible to make this happen use stored procedure ?
Thx for your attention.

Note: use Navicat for build a stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to get the union query.

```
begin

select group_concat(concat('select * from db_',yr,'.tablename') separator '\nunion all\n') into @unionqry
from (select `Year` as yr from db_name.tablename group by `Year`) t;

prepare stmt from @unionqry;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

end
```